# Get items not in list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Got 2 lists, I want to be able to get a list of the missing propId for each of the CertID using C#

list1
CertID , PropID
10,1
11,3

list2
propId, Name
1,Prop1
2,Prop2
3,Prop3

Result list
CertId,   PropId
10,2
10,3
11,1
11,2

```
  var rows = list1.Where(ra => !List2.AsEnumerable().Any(rb => rb.Propid == ra.propid)).tolist();
```

Comment: Mind helping us understand what you've tried so far @trailerman?

Comment: What have you tried? The lack of an actual question makes it seem like you just want someone to do it for you, which is not what this site is about.

Comment: @mclark1129.. I new to the whole linq thing... don't really know where to start sorry. Just need some help to point me in the right direction. Not asking for anyone to do it for me, but some understanding of how to achieve solving the problem.

Comment: Show the non-linq solution, then. The point is to see the code you have so we can see where to help.

Comment: @trailerman Totally understandable, unfortunately the question is a bit open-ended to make it a good fit for SO's format.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a starting place on to better format things.  I think ultimately you're going to want to try a specific solution and report back with any errors or invalid results you might be receiving.

Comment: Start by removing `AsEnumerable()`. It isn't useful in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**SelectMany**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) to flatten the whole list, like the following code :

```
var result = list1
    .SelectMany(x => list2
        .Where(y => y.PropId != x.PropId)
        .Select(y => new Test { CertId = x.CertId, PropId = y.PropId }))
    .ToList();
```

For test :

1 - Classes:

```
public class Test
{
    public int CertId { get; set; }
    public int PropId { get; set; }
}

public class Prop
{
    public int PropId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2 - Initialization of collections:

```
List<Test> list1 = new List<Test>
{
    new Test{CertId=10,PropId=1},
    new Test{CertId=11,PropId=3},
};

List<Prop> list2 = new List<Prop>
{
    new Prop{PropId=1,Name="prop1"},
    new Prop{PropId=2,Name="prop2"},
    new Prop{PropId=3,Name="prop3"},
};
```

3 - Query :

```
var result = list1
    .SelectMany(x => list2
        .Where(y => y.PropId != x.PropId)
        .Select(y => new Test { CertId = x.CertId, PropId = y.PropId }))
    .ToList();
```

4 - Demo :

```
foreach(Test test in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"CertId : {test.CertId}, PropId : {test.PropId}");
}
```

5 - Result:

```
CertId : 10, PropId : 2
CertId : 10, PropId : 3
CertId : 11, PropId : 1
CertId : 11, PropId : 2
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I see for your problem is to compute the cartesian product of the items and find the difference (example with tuples, I don't know which type you use in your lists)

```
        // Your Data
        var list1 = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
        {
            new Tuple<int, int>(10,1),
            new Tuple<int, int>(11,3),
        };

        var list2 = new List<Tuple<int, string>>
        {
            new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Prop1"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Prop2"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Prop3")
        };

        // Find the certIds and propIds, you might already have them from another source
        var certIds = list1.Select(x => x.Item1);
        var propIds = list2.Select(x => x.Item1);

        // Create cartesian product of certId x propId
        var possibilities =
        from cert in certIds
        from prop in propIds
        select new Tuple<int, int>(cert, prop);

        // Find the difference between these possibilities and what you have currently
        var missing = possibilities.Except(list1);

        // Example display
        foreach (var miss in missing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{miss.Item1},{miss.Item2}");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cross join and then filter for not equals:

```
var results = (
    from l1 in list1
    from l2 in list2 
    where l1.PropId != l2.PropId
    select new { l1.CertId, l2.PropId }
).ToList();
```

Unfortunately, LINQ only allows 'equals' in the 'on' operator for a join statement.  So you can't use that.